# How to compile Libmicrohttpd in Windows?

Tags: windows, gnu

I want to compile [Libmicrohttpd 0.9.34](http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/libmicrohttpd/libmicrohttpd-0.9.34.tar.gz) to a DLL(with .lib), and I can use it in my application.
Is there any guide about this? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The tar file of Libmicrohttpd does not contain a Makefile or configure file for Win32. I've compiled libmicrohttpd-0.9.37.tar.gz using [MinGW and MYSY](http://www.mingw.org/). The steps are quit simple, the same as any other GNU projects, just need to run

```
./configure
make
make install
```

The files should be copied to the `/local` folder under `MSYS`.

**HOWEVER**, please compile [pthreads-win32](http://www.sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/) under MinGW **first**.